# Where to ask questions about food

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to find an appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask about food. I am particularly interested in the name of a local Swiss cheese. Which is the appropriate site to ask similar questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a cooking offshoot to Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344102/is-there-a-cooking-offshoot-to-stack-exchange)

Comment: @Randal'Thor this question is almost 5 years older than the linked one. How can *it* be the duplicate?

Comment: Duplication isn't only based on age. I voted to close this one as duplicate because pointing "questions about food" to "cooking Stack Exchange" seems to make more sense than vice versa.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The list of all sites can be found here: [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#).

The one you want is:
[Seasoned Advice - cooking.stackexchange.com](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour)

Which is all about cooking, but specifically they have a tag "[cheese](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/cheese/info)", which states:

> Questions about the **identification**, use, storage, and sometimes
> production of cheese.

---

I'll include a few other sites which are related to "food" in case anyone else comes here from a "food" related search.

[fitness.stackexchange.com](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/tour)
Which is about fitness, but they also talk about fitness related diets and foods.

[health.stackexchange.com](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour)
Which is all about health, but also includes food safety questions and some other food related things.

Potentially related (ish), there is also [coffee.stackexchange.com](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour), which is all about coffee.

Comment: Coffee is food?

Comment: on the matter of "food from a place you don't live" there is a certain amount of "what is this [snack, drink, meal] that I ate/drank in [place I visited]?" on travel.se also. The cheese question might belong there.

Comment: As a developer, coffee is not only food and mandatory to function properly, but it's also the quintessential source of energy (possibly placebo to avoid debates). Honest, more coffee = less bugs in prod!