# Is there a cooking offshoot to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would love to know where to ask and answer cooking and food preparation or ingredient related questions as well as to ask about the history of some types of foods or dishes, their preparations, and recipes. If there is not a cooking related Stack Exchange, I will recommend or ask about one in the Area 51 stack exchange.

Comment: Have you looked at the list of SE sites?

Comment: Maybe the OP simply wasn't  aware that a list of SE sites exists. I know I discovered the page weeks or maybe even months after I had joined.  Why all the downvotes on someone who is a totally new user is beyond me. Can people on MSE be more forgiving and patient?

Comment: For future reference: https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest and [Life&Arts](https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts-oldest)

Comment: I found [cooking.se] using Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=cooking+stack+exchange

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Excellent point. And once you find the list, it's pretty huge. OP probably expected to find a site with the word "Cooking" in the title. There is also a search box in the hamburger menu with the site list where one could type "Cooking" and be led to Seasoned Advice. It was a while before I even realized it was there.

Comment: Is everyone ignoring that Seasoned advice was posted in an answer to this question over 11 hours ago? Actually I did not notice a cooking site in this list that I found: https://stackexchange.com/sites but I had not yet heard that it was called Seasoned Advice and I did not see the Chef's hat logo. Now I know, thanks to Robert Longson.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There certainly is it's called [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)

You [can ask about](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> - Cooking & food preparation methods
> - Kitchen equipment
> - Food handling and storage
> - Ingredient selection and use
> - Recipe comprehension, improvement, and repairs
> - The history of food and cooking

there.